# Toggle button click error occure in android

Tags: android

I have added list view Top Toggle button

**For Example** If i have selected Veg means veg item show it in list view

Non veg item selected means Non veg item show it .

But First Time i got it Non veg item but when i was clicked `Toggle button` i called URL that time i m occurred is type of error.Please give me solution.Below that error

Error :

```
03-11 22:30:43.059: WARN/dalvikvm(385): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-11 22:30:43.129: WARN/ActivityManager(70):   Force finishing activity com.doodleblue.dinein/.ui.vegnonveg
03-11 22:30:43.730: WARN/ActivityManager(70): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4504b9a0 com.doodleblue.dinein/.ui.vegnonveg}
03-11 22:30:53.172: WARN/ActivityManager(70): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
03-11 22:30:53.810: WARN/ActivityManager(70): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{450beb20 com.doodleblue.dinein/.ui.listviewitem}
03-11 22:30:58.957: WARN/ActivityManager(70): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{4504b9a0 com.doodleblue.dinein/.ui.vegnonveg}
```

Comment: don't call urls on ui thread

Comment: ya i have use it AsyncTask but at that time i called three URL For example First URL i have post get id and i have past it next URL in post execute and get restaurant id and previous like that post  execute called next URL ..